# Stop scrolling on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile

I need to stop scrolling on click, I currently have the following code which works on a desktop browser but not on mobile:

**JS**

```
$('.gallery-button, .slide-show-holder .menu-close-button').on('click', function() {
   $('html').toggleClass('no-scroll').scrollTop(0);
});
```

**CSS**

```
.no-scroll {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class='gallery-button'>Show Gallery</div>
```

Any help much appreciated

Comment: If you put `.no-scroll` class on `body` it should do its job. I've tried it on mobile and it's worked perfectly.

Comment: wow that actually worked, i thought i tried this already, make an answer and ill mark it correct ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you put `.no-scroll` class on `body` it should do its job

CSS:

```
.no-scroll {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

HTML

```
<body class="no-scroll">
```